# How can I position a Font Awesome icon in an SVG circle?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, font-awesome

How do I get the trophy to be inside the circle, right under the 2000?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="text-center content-align-items">
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="4" style="opacity: 0.8;stroke: rgb(76, 182, 172);fill:white"/>
    <text fill="#000000" font-size="18" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="center">
       <tspan x="50" y="55">20000 <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i></tspan>
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/owc4kmLv/

Comment: Your question is tagged with Bootstrap 5, yet you loaded Bootstrap 4 (and jQuery, for some reason) in your Fiddle demo. No need to send us to other sites, and please be sure your tags and your code match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `<i>` is not a part of SVG, so browser moves it outside of the `<svg>` element.
You might use another `<tspan>` though with the corresponding HTML entity `&#xf091;`:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="text-center content-align-items">
  <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="4" style="opacity: 0.8;stroke: rgb(76, 182, 172);fill:white"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-size="18" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="center">
            <tspan x="50" y="55">20000</tspan>
            <tspan x="50" y="75" class="fa">&#xf091;</tspan>
        </text>
    </svg>


</div>
```

Comment: fa works, thank you for that, but for some reason ph icons dont work
https://demo.interface.club/limitless/demo/template/html/layout_1/full/icons_phosphor.html i tried using the html code provided on that page, but doesnt work when i put <tspan x="50" y="75" class="ph">&#xf30c</tspan>

Comment: @Zoinky, you have to have the font Phosphor loaded and applied to the tspan. Just adding classname is not enough.

Comment: this worked
<tspan x="50" y="75" class="ph ph-1x">&#xf60b</tspan>

Comment: @Zoinky, good to know you've made it!

Comment: thank you, not sure why adding that extra class made a diff but it did

Comment: @Zoinky, you can inspect the element and see what exactly applied the font-family.